# How to test interaction between WatchKit app and paired iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I'm trying to test an iOS app with its paired WatchKit app (iOS 9 + WatchOS2). So far I know how to test them one by one:

1) By testing the scheme "WKMyApp" using "My iPhone + My Apple Watch" I can test out if the WatchKit App is running well on my watch.

2) By testing the scheme "MyApp" using "My iPhone" I can test out if the iOS app is running well on my phone.

However, since I'm trying to use the new WatchConnectivity framework to realize exchange of a file between my phone and the watch, how can I test them at the same time? Can I test them together meanwhile being able to see log from both apps?